# Why I need different declarations for **ptr and *ptr[]?

Tags: c, pointers

I thought that `char *ptrs[];` and `char **strs;` should be the same thing.
At least I can use both as string arrays.

When I try to compile `char **strs`, it's fine, but `*ptrs[]` want to be initialized or at least it want a fixed size for some reason.

```
char ptrs[];
char **strs;
```

I get the error:

```
gcc: "error: array size missing in ‘ptrs’"
```

Comment: First of all you forgot the asterisk in `char ptrs[];`. Secondly you can't define non-argument variables as arrays without a size. Thirdly, C and C++ are two different languages which have different rules, like for example the use of unsized arrays (which are allowed in *one* place by the C standard, but not by the C++ standard).

Comment: Arrays and pointer are not the same thing

Answer (score 4):

> I thought that `char *ptrs[];` and `char **strs;` should be he same thing.

You thought wrong. First is an array of unspecified size of pointers. The second is a pointer to a pointer. An array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array.

You may have been confused by function parameters. Function parameters cannot be arrays and if you write an array parameter, it is adjusted to be a pointer to an element of such array. As such, in a parameter declaration the first is adjusted to be the same as the second. This adjustment only occurs in parameter declarations and nowhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and pointers are two different derived types.

If you declare an object with automatic storage duration then it shall have a complete type. For arrays it means that the number of elements in the array shall be known (either explicitly specified or calculated according to provided initializes).

So the compiler issue the error

```
gcc: "error: array size missing in ‘ptrs’"
```

for this declaration of an array with the automatic storage duration

```
char *ptrs[];
```

(I think you mean the type specifier char * instead of char when you are comparing these two declarations `char *ptrs[];` and `char **strs;`) because it is unable to determine how much memory to allocate for the array.

On the other hand, pointers are always complete object types. From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types, p.#20)

> A pointer type is a complete object type.

As a result the compiler always knows the size of a pointer.

If this declaration

```
char *ptrs[];
```

has file scope then such an incomplete declaration is allowed and is named as a tentative definition. the compiler will interpret it like this declaration

```
char *ptrs[1];
```

is present at the end of a translation unit.

Arrays used in expressions are implicitly (with rare exceptions) are converted to pointers to their first elements. So this array designator `ptrs` used in expressions as for example a function argument is converted to rvalue of the type `char **`.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that `char *ptrs[];` and `char **strs;` should be the same thing. At least I can use both as string arrays.

Your assumption is not true and neither of those two can be used as "*arrays of strings*". An *array of strings* (if this term is anyhow in any manner appropriate) is after my opinion, an array of array of `char`s, where a *string* can be stored in each array of `char`s which is therefore again an element of the array of arrays. A pointer cannot store a string. It can only point to one.

`char **strs;` - `strs` is a pointer to pointer to `char`.

`char *ptrs[];` - `ptrs` is an array of pointer to `char` with unspecified amount of elements. That is not permissible anywhere else than as function parameter.

As function parameter `char *ptrs[]` is equal to `char **ptrs` and denotes a pointer to pointer to `char`, but again it stores no strings itself.

If you use `char *ptrs[]` as usual declaration, the compiler needs to know the amounts of pointer elements in the array.

This is why you get the error message

> "*error: array size missing in `‘ptrs’`*"

with GCC.

Answer (score 1):

The two declarations are equivalent *only* as function parameter declarations:

```
void foo( char *ptrs[], char **strs ) { ... }
```

because any parameter of type `T a[N]` or `T a[]` is "adjusted" to `T *a`.  This is due to the fact that array expressions "decay" to pointer expressions under most circumstances - when you pass an array expression as a function argument, what the function actually receives is a pointer expression.

As regular variable declarations, however, the two are *not* equivalent.  An array definition must either specify a size or have an initializer:

```
char *ptrs[] = {"foo", "bar", "bletch", "blurga", ... };
```

In this case, the array size will be taken from the number of elements in the initializer.